# what is the consequence of setting enableQueryTimeouts to FALSE?

Tags: mysql, java

MySQL Connector-J has a property enableQueryTimeouts which is TRUE by default. However, in the documentation it is mentioned as :

> When enabled, query timeouts set via Statement.setQueryTimeout() use a shared java.util.Timer instance for scheduling. Even if the timeout doesn't expire before the query is processed, there will be memory used by the TimerTask for the given timeout which won't be reclaimed until the time the timeout would have expired if it hadn't been cancelled by the driver. **High-load environments might want to consider disabling this functionality**

So, I want to disable enableQueryTimeouts to gain high performance. However, if I disable enableQueryTimeouts, then

1. How a query will timeout?
2. Will there any consequences ?

Please help

Comment: This seems to be connector/Java specific timeout. Even when disabled the queries might still timeout on lock waits etc, but it would be a different mechanism.

Comment: The [official documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connectors/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html) for reference.

Answer (score -1):

Consequences: if there is a slow query(s) your system will be too slow, hang, or even go out of memory.

if QueryTimeout is disabled  from MySQL or the connector it will stay until its finished (how to enable it from MySQL `SET GLOBAL MAX_STATEMENT_TIME=XXX;  -- where XXX=number`

Comment: Note:  Not available until 5.7.4; a flurry of fixes occurred in 5.7.8.